# call super in constructor of ViewModel instance class : Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I am new to Kotlin.
Here is is my java code I wanted to convert it in kotlin

```
public class FavouritesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private FavouritesDBHelper mFavHelper;
    private ArrayList<Favourites> mFavs;

    FavouritesViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mFavHelper = new FavouritesDBHelper(application);
    }
}
```

but I am getting compile time errors at constructor

code what I tried:

```
public class FavoritesDataViewModel:ViewModel{
    private lateinit var mFavHelper: DatabaseHelper
    private lateinit var mfav:ArrayList<Favorites>

    public constructor(application: Application): super(application){
        mFavHelper = DatabaseHelper(application)
    }
}
```

getting error at `super(application)`

Thanks

Comment: from java to kotlin convert use this https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt

Comment: you can use here default constructor like 
FavouritesViewModel constructor(application:Application):AndroidViewModel(application)

Comment: Thanks @Shweta, got the answer I am extending ViewModel instead of AndroidViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FavoritesDataViewModel:AndroidViewModel{
    private lateinit var mFavHelper: DatabaseHelper
    private lateinit var mfav:ArrayList<Favorites>

    public constructor(application: Application): super(application){
        mFavHelper = DatabaseHelper(application)
    }
}
```

this solved my issue, I am using `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FavoritesDataViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application){
    private var mFavHelper: DatabaseHelper
    private lateinit var mfav:ArrayList<Favorites>
    init{
       mFavHelper = DatabaseHelper(getApplication<Application>())
    }

    public constructor(application: Application): super(application){
        mFavHelper = DatabaseHelper(application)
    }
}
```

This will help you calling super call to pass arguments and safer to access application instance for viewModel purpose. And help you to avoid latinit properties as well.